# Why does importing numpy prints 2313 to the screen?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm seeing this really strange behavior where my script outputs the number 2313 when I import numpy. It annoys me, but I don't know why it happens and what I can do about it. I'm using python 3.11.0 and numpy version 1.23.4.

When my script is empty and I run it, nothing happens. However, when I write:

`import numpy as np`

with the rest of my script still completely empty, I get the output:

[image: output to screen]

Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: Have you tried running a debugger to trace your script's execution?

Comment: @kmkurn Would that be able to tell me something, with my script being completely empty except for the "import numpy as np" line? If so, do I need an IDE to run a debugger? I'm now writing my scripts in Sublime.

Comment: A debugger helps trace a program’s execution. In this case, it can help you find the unexpected print statement, which seems located in your NumPy package. You don’t need an IDE. Just use [the built-in pdb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html).

Comment: @kmkurn Thanks a lot. Following your suggestion I was eventually able to find the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the debugger gave me the following error message:

`AttributeError: module 'signal' has no attribute 'SIGINT'`

This led me to this question:
[Python3 AttributeError: module 'signal' has no attribute 'getsignal'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62766672/python3-attributeerror-module-signal-has-no-attribute-getsignal)

This is practically the same problem, with the same solution. There was a local file name signal.py which turned out to print the value 2313 to the screen. Renaming that file solved the issue.